# How to specify a global render() method of a python standard library object instances in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, render

I want to render all `datetime` objects in **all** templates in a django application in a certain manner, using common code for all datetime objects that might be passed all the way to the template.

Without going too much in to details, please note that **the following are *not* viable otions.**:

- use a filter or a custom template tag in the template
- subclassing datetime
- setting `DATETIME_FORMAT` to a magic value
- using a custom timezone and some TimeZoneMiddlWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own datetime class and monkeypatch the datetime module early in the app setup.
(Maybe you need to monkeypatch all imported modules too, depends on how early you can do this

```
 import datetime

 class mydatetime(object):
     ...
     def render(self):
         ...

 datetime.datetime = mydatetime
```

It's easier if you subclass the datetime object for sure, but you don't have to.